# Running app in Ionic View I cannot seem to access external URL's

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a cordova app that when running on my device can access an external API - however when I use my app in the Ionic View Simulator on either an Android or iOS device I am no longer able to connect to any external URL (e.g my login doesn't work).

Is there anything in Ionic View that would prevent me from accessing external URL's?

-- update --
The app shows a blank white screen in the Ionic View.

The only plugins installed are as follows:

- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-file
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer
- cordova-plugin-native-transitions
- cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: are you using the latest version of ionic-cli ?

Comment: I am running Ionic CLI 1.4.5

Comment: The external api is running on your localhost?

Comment: Good call - this is a public API however I do get a white screen on iOS which makes it hard to debug

Comment: It seems a tough problem. I've tried it with one of my apps and it works great (android). Blank page means there are some references which cannot be resolved. You can try and run `adb -s <yourdevice> logcat CordovaLog:D *:S` and you can get your device `adb devices` (android).